# How do I create a static library with GCC compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, static-libraries, compiler-optimization

I have a function to compute dot product in C++. I want to compile this function with -O3 compiler optimization. Rest of the codes in my codebase are compiled with -O0. To do this, I have created a static library that contains the function and compiled the library with -O3. Then I have linked the library to my code. But I am not getting the optimization from my library.

**test.cpp**

```
#include "config.h"
int multiply(uint128 *X1, uint128 *Y1, uint128 &ans, int input_length)
{
    int i=0;
    ans = 0;
    if (input_length > 4)
    {
        for (; i < input_length - 4; i += 4)
        {
            ans += X1[i] * Y1[i];
            ans += X1[i + 1] * Y1[i + 1];
            ans += X1[i + 2] * Y1[i + 2];
            ans += X1[i + 3] * Y1[i + 3];
        }
    }
    for (; i < input_length; i++)
    {
        ans += X1[i] * Y1[i];
    }    
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int len = 500, wrapper = 50;
    uint128 a[len], b[len], ans;
    auto start = time_now, end = time_now;
    long long ctr = 0;
    for(int t = 0; t < wrapper; t++)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < len; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand();
            b[i] = rand();
        }
        start = time_now;
        multiply(a, b, ans, len);
        end = time_now;
        ctr += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count();
    }
    cout<<"time taken: "<<ctr<<endl;
}
```

```
Compilation:
g++ -O3 test.cpp -std=c++11
./a.out
time taken: 1372
```

**optimized.hpp**

```
#ifndef OPTIMIZED_HPP
#define OPTIMIZED_HPP
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef __uint128_t uint128;


int multiply(uint128 *X1, uint128 *Y1, uint128 &ans, int input_length);
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "optimized.hpp"
typedef __uint128_t uint128;

#define time_now std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()

int main()
{

    int len = 500, wrapper = 50;
    uint128 a[len], b[len], ans;

    auto start = time_now, end = time_now;
    long long ctr = 0;

    for(int t = 0; t < wrapper; t++)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < len; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rand();
            b[i] = rand();
        }

        start = time_now;
        multiply(a, b, ans, len);
        end = time_now;
        ctr += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count();
    }
    cout<<"time taken: "<<ctr<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Compilation:
(the name of the library file is optimized.cpp)
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -c optimized.cpp
ar rcs libfast.a optimized.o
g++ main.cpp libfast.a -std=c++11 -O3
./a.out 
time taken: 36140
```

Comment: is the function templated? Or inlined?

Comment: No. Question edited. I have added the function.

Comment: We also need to see the source code of `main.cpp`, or a simpler program that
exhibits the same problem, *plus* the evidence that it does exhibit the problem.

Comment: Question edited. @MikeKinghan

Comment: Can you stop posting photos please

Comment: @sad_man Almost there. Along with the output of each program you
need to tell us the command(s) you used to compile and
link it. In the question please (not in comments). Commands,
code and program output all from the same compile-link-&-run.
(This is what's called a [mcve] - the most efficient way to
get coding questions answered on SO.)

Comment: Thanks @MikeKinghan. added that

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you've perpetrated the class foot-shoot: *I optimised away the function I was trying to time*. We all did it once.

You've optimised the `test.cpp` program `-O3`. The compiler observes that the program ignores
the return value of `multiply`. It also has the definition of `multiply` to hand
and observes that the body has no external effects but the ignored return value (in any case constant `0`) and ignored reference parameter `ans`. So the line:

```
multiply(a, b, ans, len);
```

might as well be:

```
(void)0;
```

and the optimiser culls it.

You can rectify this by amending the program so that it uses external effects of `multiply` in a way that affects the output of the program and can't be predicted just by knowing the definition of the function.

But that's not enough. `-O3` optimisation of `test.cpp` when the
compiler can see the definition of `multiply` is still going to have
a major information advantage over the same optimisation of `main.cpp`,
where `multiply` is just an external reference to a black box.

To measure meaningfully the speed of `multiply` with `-O3`
optimisation against its speed with `-O0` optimisation you must measure in
each case *with other things being equal*. So at least do this:

(Inadvertently my `test.cpp` is your `main.cpp`)

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -O0 -o mult_O0.o optimized.cpp
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -O3 -o mult_O3.o optimized.cpp
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -O3 -o test.o test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:13: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Wvla]
   13 |     uint128 a[len], b[len], ans;
      |             ^
test.cpp:13:21: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Wvla]
   13 |     uint128 a[len], b[len], ans;
      |                     ^
```

(You might care about those warnings)

```
$ g++ -o tmult_O0 test.o mult_O0.o
$ g++ -o tmult_O3 test.o mult_O3.o
$ ./tmult_O0
time taken: 228461
$ ./tmult_O3
time taken: 99092
```

which shows that `-O3` is doing its stuff.

And if you do it like that, you *don't* need to make sure you use the effects of `multiply` in `test.cpp`, because now compiler knows that it cannot know the effects of the black box `multiply(a, b, ans, len)` and cannot cull it.